# Hash MD5 via PHP showing different result than via Unix Terminal

Tags: php, linux, unix, hash, terminal

## Goal

I tried to make a hash out of my user **device mac** +  **URI** that they attempt to visit

---

## Tried

I tried in **Terminal** on my **Mac OS** by executing

`echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"`

I got

`QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw`

---

I tried it in php

```
$client_mac = Session::get('client_mac');
$original_uri = Session::get('original_uri');
$clean_uri = urldecode($original_uri);
$cmd = 'echo -n "'.$client_mac.'||'.$clean_uri.'" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"';

//cmd = echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"

$clean_url_hash = exec($cmd);
//$clean_url_hash = t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g
```

I've tried `exec()` and `shell_exec()` - same result.

I got

`t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g`

---

## Result

Terminal

> QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw

PHP

> t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g

---

Why is that ? Any ideas, anyone ?

---

## More details

---

Detail PHP function

```
public function forward(){

    $cp_host = env('CAPTIVE_PORTAL_HOST');
    $client_mac = Session::get('client_mac');
    $original_uri = Session::get('original_uri');
    $clean_uri = urldecode($original_uri);

    $cmd = 'echo -n "'.$client_mac.'||'.$clean_uri.'" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"';

    $clean_url_hash = exec($cmd);

    //dd($clean_url_hash); <--- I got t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g
    //dd(get_defined_vars());

    Session::put('c_'.$clean_url_hash,$original_uri);
    Session::put('clean_url_hash',$clean_url_hash);
    return Redirect::to($cp_host.'fbwifi/auth?c='.$clean_url_hash);

}
```

---

Variables Value of the function

```
dd(get_defined_vars()); will return 

array:6 [▼
  "cp_host" => "http://localhost:8888/"
  "client_mac" => "00:00:11:22:33:44"
  "original_uri" => "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bunlongheng.com"
  "clean_uri" => "http://www.bunlongheng.com"
  "cmd" => "echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_""
  "clean_url_hash" => "t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g"
]
```

Comment: both produce the exact same hash here, so it's undoubtedly SOME invisible character that didn't survive the cut&paste process. You'll have to examine BOTH of your input strings to see what the byte-level difference is. And the hash I got is your "terminal" version as well, for both lines.

Comment: @MarcB : wait, what is the result of your php ? if you run `exec($cmd);` - where $cmd = `echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"`

Comment: I get the QN... hash no matter how I run it. from within php, or directly at the command line.

Comment: @MarcB : I've updated my post. Can you please take a peek at it ? I hope I didn't really do anything that I'm not suppose to.

Comment: simple testing: use `var_dump()` on all your variables. vardump will report string lengths as well, so if you have a different length between the two versions, you KNOW there's some difference between the strings, even though they're visually identical. just because two strings LOOK identical, doesn't mean they actually are.

Comment: `var_dump($clean_url_hash)` return `"t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g"` , `dd($clean_url_hash)` also return `"t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g"`

Comment: I'm very confuse now. I wish I can see `QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw` as you claimed you see.

Comment: If you execute this `echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"` in your `shell_exec()` , what do you see ?

Comment: QN... as expected.

Comment: No way, can I see the screenshot of that. :P. Jk.

Comment: copy-pasted exactly your text into both a php shell_exec(), and directly to a terminal prompt. both give the same hash.

Comment: So do u know why I got diff result than you  ? Maybe if I can dehash my `t7Xnq9ClfRWciqFAYXbu7g` - all of these will be reveal. What do u think ?

Comment: so start debugging: eliminate ALL Of the hashing/b64/tr stuff. just capture `shell_exec('echo...')` and see what you get back. maybe the shell that php's using for the exec is adding some other text. And no, you can't de-hash. That's the whole point of hashes. they're a meat grinder. cow goes in, hamburger comes out. you cannot take the hamburger and glue it back together into a cow, let alone the original cow.

Comment: Ohh..wow.. great example. I'll debug on this more. Also, I think of another possible solution, if I have the `echo string` in a file, and read that file, and execute the string in that file. Do u think it will give me diff result ? I was trying to avoid using `shell_exec()`. If not, I'll stop.

Comment: On my linux box I get the same results. On my Mac I get different results. Huh.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue, and I don't know the answer. Do you have to generate a hash like this though? Why not just use PHP's `md5` function, or something simple like that?

Comment: @jszobody : I don't know other functions beside `shell_exec()` , `exec()`, and `system()`. Please kindly suggest.

Comment: @ihue In php `md5("00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com");` would give you a hash of the MAC and uri. No calls to the command line. No need for openssl.

Comment: @jszobody : there is a certain hash that Facebook allow, unfortunately, I can't just use the regular `md5()` function.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I just to stick with something that return me as I would have execute this `echo -n "00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com" | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"`

Comment: @ihue See my answer below, confirmed this is generating the same hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate this same hash using PHP functions, with no shell call.

Like this:

```
$hash = rtrim(base64_encode(md5("00:00:11:22:33:44||http://www.bunlongheng.com", true)),'=');
// QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/KkR9v

Comment: You have no idea, how much I owed you. :) You're awesome.

Comment: How would turn this in to PHP ?  `echo -n "123||http://localhost:8888/fbwifi/auth?c=QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac abc -binary | base64 | tr -d "=" | tr "+/" "-_"` return `BZQ-DtGpjQYBP-OBPfKJb7ZQxnNU1iQ1XgxOy4CAMn8`

Comment: If it is too much to ask, I'll create a new question with what I have tried.

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php? You can specify the algo (sha256), provide your string, your key (abc) raw_output (binary), and then wrap base in base64_encode just like I did in my answer.

Comment: Here you go https://3v4l.org/tDeYv. But seriously... read the PHP docs, that are quite helpful. =)

Comment: I've tried `hash_hmac('sha256',base64_encode('123||http://localhost:8888/fbwifi/auth?c=QNyia8Q2VvKNJapAAVfXQw'),'abc');` and I got something way off. `c844fbbbea0a3892b6e173c2c851ca157732243d69eda36d1f633875dc0b8bde`

Comment: I have 2 questions for you because I want to learn it, and know how to do it my self.

Comment: 1 - How do you know to use `trim(strtr(` at the beginning of it ?

Comment: Keep in mind that in a shell command, you read from left-to-ride. Each step separated by a pipe. Whereas in Php it's functional, you read from inside-out.

Comment: So in shell `step1 | step2 | step2` becomes like `step3(step2(step1()));` in PHP.

Comment: 2- How do you know how to place `base64_encode` in front of `(hash_hmac(` ?

Comment: I guess your answer apply to both of my questions. Now, I see the patterns.

Comment: Your steps are: 1) Use input string 2) create hmac 3) base64_encode 4) strip off unwanted characters. In php that becomes `strip characters ( base64_encode ( hash_hmac( input string ) ) )`

Comment: See this new solution: https://3v4l.org/7sQCl. Pretty much the same code, but expanded so you can follow the steps. (Sorry, fixed link).